# Get/dump/download page after ajax response comes

Tags: ruby, ajax, nokogiri, response

Here sample code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

begin
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
rescue
    puts "Fehler ist aufgetretten..."
end
```

Some parts of the page are loaded asynchronous and i'm missing some values, which are loaded later. Is there any way to open the url, to wait 10 seconds and after that to assign it to the variable **doc**? Any solutions/ideas with bash/lynx/wget are welcome too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, waiting 10 seconds isn't going to work, because neither open-uri nor Nokogiri will execute the javascript that loads content asynchronously. You'll need to use a browser driver like [Watir](http://watir.com/) or [Watir-webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/). If JRuby is an option, you can use [Celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/) which is a browser emulator that supports *some* javascript (using the Watir API), and will likely perform the task you need.